# Prove complex number inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

$$
\left| {\frac{{z_1  + z_2 }}{{z_3  + z_4 }}} \right| \le \frac{{\left| {z_1 } \right| + \left| {z_2 } \right|}}{{\Big | {\left| {z_3 } \right| - \left| {z_4 } \right|} \Big  |}}
$$

I know that you can rewrite this as
$$
\left| {\frac{{z_1  + z_2 }}{{z_3  -( -z_4 )}}} \right| \le \frac{{\left| {z_1 } \right| + \left| {z_2 } \right|}}{{\Big | {\left| {z_3 } \right| - \left| {-z_4 } \right|} \Big |}}
$$
Further, I know that the triangular inequalities are:
abs=absolute value

1. $\operatorname{abs}(z_1+z_2)\leq \operatorname{abs}(z_1) +\operatorname{abs}(z_2)$
2. $\operatorname{abs}\big(\operatorname{abs}(z_1)-\operatorname{abs}(z_2)\big) \leq \operatorname{abs}(z_1-z_2)$

but I'm not sure how to put these ideas together

Comment: In comparing the first fraction to the second, the numerator has stayed the same or increased, while the denominator has stayed the same or decreased. So the first fraction is less or equal to second.

Comment: but how do I prove the statement?

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: @Samantha Don't know why you deleted and reposted the [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4356339/how-would-i-solve-this-triangular-inequality) instead of editing the old one.

Comment: sorry the question was closed so I thought I couldn't do anything about it. Will keep it in mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|z_1+z_1|\leqslant|z_1|+|z_2|$ and $|z_3+z_4|=|z_3-(-z_4)|\geqslant\bigl||z_3|-|z_4|\bigr|$, you have$$\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3+z_4}\right|=\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_3+z_4|}\leqslant\frac{|z_1|+|z_2|}{\bigl||z_3|-|z_4|\bigr|}.$$

Comment: So in the LHS the denominator is greater  but the numerator is less which proves the statement?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why do you mention $\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3-z_4}\right|=\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_3-z_4|}?$

Comment: @miracle173 Because I misunderstood the question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @miracle173 What is it that you don't understand?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Why you write $\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3-z_4}\right|=\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_3-z_4|}?$ This is a trivial identity . I suspect that you want to write only $\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3-z_4}\right|$ instead of this.

Comment: @miracle173 Since I did *not* write that, I cannot answer your question.

Comment: Sorry. I see that you  changed it now to $ \left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3+z_4}\right|=\frac{|z_1+z_2|}{|z_3+z_4|}.$ But I still don't understand.

Comment: @miracle173 I started by proving something about $|z_1+z_2|$ and about $|z_3+z_4|$. In order to use that information, I had to turn the expression $\left|\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_3+z_4}\right|$ into something that used those numbers.

Comment: One should consider the case $|z_4|=|z_3|$ separately.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe If $|z_3|=|z_4|$, then the inequality makes no sense.

Comment: I still don't understand, but this does not matter. I wanted to point you to an expresison that I thought you want to repaitr. But if it's ok for you, then it's ok for me, too.